# Mysql query to check username and password using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table to store the user details and it include fields such as email,mobile and password. Here my username to login can be either email or mobile number and I need to compare it with password. How can I write the query for it? I have written it like this, but it's not working

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('email',$data['email']);
        $this->db->or_where('mobile',$data['email']);

        $this->db->where('password',$data['password']);

        $this->db->get()->row();
```

I need code to compare username as either email or mobile with its password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is specified on official CodeIgniter documentation (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping), you can group "where" statements. So, for achieving what you need, you should do the following:

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('user')
    ->group_start()
        ->where('email',$data['email'])
        ->or_where('mobile',$data['email'])
    ->group_end()
    ->where('password',$data['password'])
    ->get();
```